# How to set marker color in XL_CHART_TYPE.LINE_MARKERS

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

How to set marker color (line, and body of marker) when using XL_CHART_TYPE.LINE_MARKERS?
Tricks like `chart.plots[0].series[0].marker.fill.fore_color = pptx.dml.color.RGBColor(0,0,0)` don't work

Below an sample of code:

```
import traceback
import sys
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import ChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.util import Inches
import pptx
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Cm, Pt
from pptx.enum.text import MSO_ANCHOR,MSO_VERTICAL_ANCHOR, MSO_AUTO_SIZE,PP_ALIGN
from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData, ChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_TICK_MARK
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_LEGEND_POSITION
from pptx.dml.chtfmt import ChartFormat
from pptx.dml.line import LineFormat
from pptx.dml.color import ColorFormat, RGBColor
from pptx.enum.dml import MSO_LINE
prs = Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])
chart_data = ChartData()
chart_data.categories = ['Q1 Sales', 'Q2 Sales', 'Q3 Sales']
chart_data.add_series('West',    (32.2, 28.4, 34.7))
chart_data.add_series('East',    (24.3, 30.6, 20.2))
chart_data.add_series('Midwest', (20.4, 18.3, 26.2))
x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(6), Inches(4.5)
chart = slide.shapes.add_chart(
    XL_CHART_TYPE.LINE_MARKERS, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data
).chart
chart.has_legend = True
chart.legend.include_in_layout = False
chart.series[0].smooth = True
chart.plots[0].series[0].marker.style = 8

try:
    fill = chart.plots[0].series[0].marker.format.fill
    fill.solid()
    fill.fore_color = RGBColor(0,0,0)
    #chart.plots[0].series[0].marker.format.line.color = RGBColor(255,0,0)
    #chart.plots[0].series[1].marker.style = 2
except Exception as error:
    traceback.print_exc()
prs.save('chart-01.pptx')
```

It produces error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):    File
>   "", line 38, in 
>   fill.fore_color = RGBColor(0,0,0)  AttributeError: can't set attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
fill = series.marker.format.fill
fill.solid()
fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(0,0,0)
```

(Note the `.format` between marker and fill.)

This sets the color for all markers for the series.

If you want to set the color of individual points, you can use something like:

```
fill = series.points[0].format.fill
fill.solid()
fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)
```

The `fill.solid()` call sets the fill type to solid, which is necessary before assigning to `.fore_color`, because not all fill types have a `.fore_color` attribute.

Comment: I've tried first of this, but error "AttributeError: can't set attribute" remained...

Comment: Post the minimum of the exact code you used that produced the error and the full stack trace (by editing your question) and I'll take a look.

Comment: You need `fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 0, 0)` (`.rgb` was missing). I've updated the code in my answer.